# no data after downloading blob pdf file

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, blob

1)I want to download a pdf file which is stored in the oracle db as a blob. But i get 0 kb file.
I havent done this before. So pls help
on button click a servlet calls another servlet which does the job of downloading.
This is the code i wrote to download the file.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try {
        OutputStream outStream = resp.getOutputStream();
        List file=(List)request.getAttribute("file");
             String fileName=null;
 byte[] fileBytes=null;
for (int i=0;i<file.size();i++)
        {
            Map objec=(Map) file.get(i);
            fileName=(String)objec.get("fileName");
            fileBytes=(byte[])objec.get("fileBytes");
             }
String fileType = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf(".")+1,fileName.length());
  if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("pdf"))
{
resp.setContentType( "application/pdf" );
}

resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+fileName+"\"");
resp.setHeader("cache-control", "must-revalidate");
System.out.println(fileBytes);
} finally { 
      //  out.close();
    }
} 
ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();

outs.write(fileBytes);
outs.flush();
outs.close();
```

Please tell me where i went wrong.How can i download the full pdf file with data?

2) Lets say this pdf file is a full report of customer details.lets assume its got 300 pages. and for each customer the page no's are known. ex for customer Antony his page no in this pdf is 4 and 5. I want to only download the file with these 2 pages.How can i accomplish this task?

UPDATE:
jtahlborn solved my first problem which was very silly...just had to add the following lines

```
resp.getOutputStream().write(fileBytes);
resp.getOutputStream().flush();
resp.getOutputStream().close();
```

So i finally succeeded with that. Now pls some1 help me for my second problem.I want to download pages for which page no's are known from the pdf and save as a separate pdf file. Actually thats the pdf i want to download. Not the first pdf. I just did that to learn to download a blob file.

Comment: Ask your second question as a separate question.  Stack Overflow is a platform for providing answers to questions.  But the only way of identifying correct answers is to have one question per thread.

Answer (score 3):

1) You are printing out the bytes instead of putting them in the response.  e.g. `resp.getOutputStream().write(fileBytes);`

2) you will probably need some sort of pdf parsing/editing library which will allow you to pull apart the pdf file.  alternately, you can use some standalone pdf editor to separate the pdf into per-customer files beforehand and store them individually in the db.

Comment: sorry..i forgot to add the remaining code....     ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();
outs.write(fileBytes);
outs.flush();
outs.close();

Comment: i have edited the topic and added the lines in which im printing the file..pls check..

Comment: oh YES mr jtahlborn....1st problem is solved...thanks a lot...now im worried abt the second problem